# How do I stop the ionic 7 error Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.ts(2345) with setTimeout

Tags: angular, ionic7

I have set an ionic 7 page with

```
setTimeout(() => {  }, 500);

() => {  } is underlined
```

I receive an error Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.ts(2345)

I think this is coming from spec.ts file as any pages that were built with ionic 6 do not have this error.  How would I silence this error so I can use setTimeout with ionic 7

Answer (score 0):

Small bug in ionic 7 seems to be fixed now.  If anyone is having the same issue delete the page update ionic and it will work now